# NSDateFormatter returns different date for simulator and device.

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using following date formatter to get date in NSString

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"];
 NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

On simulator I am getting value in dateString as - 2013-09-24T05:46:51.
But on device(IOS 7.0.6) I am getting dateString as - 2013-09-24T05:46:51 **pm**.

the **pm** part on device is extra.
Can some one tell me why this is happening and how I can remove pm from dateString so that dateString will be consistent on both simulator and device(any device with any IOS version would be helpful).

Comment: You need to set the date formatter's locale to the special locale of `en_US_POSIX`. Search on that for many examples and explanations.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you. This solved my problem. If you can pot you comment as answer I can accept it.